# Circular purple icon with white arrow inside

Tags: icons, directory, naming

There is a circular purple icon with a white arrow inside that is displayed on top of some of these folders in the root folder. What does this icon mean? It's on the sbin folder, for example. (btw, I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux and will likely ask some awfully-phrased questions at some point on here)

Comment: Since you have got the answer, you should accept this answer as the right one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image] Those are links (shortcuts to someplace else in the filesystem).

Comment: Does that mean the folder itself is ONLY a link and does not actually contain files...it just links to another folder or file?

Comment: Yes, that's what a 'link' is.